# Is array([2,1]) 1 row & 2 cols or 2 rows & 1 col?(In python numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

In python library numpy, is array([2,1]) (1,2) or (2,1)_(row,col)?

I made 3 tries below but couldn't find the answer.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2])
y = np.array([[1,3,5], [2,4,6]])
z = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
o = np.array([1,2,3])

print(np.dot(x,y))
print(np.dot(z,x))
print(np.dot(x,o))
```

The first and second one worked but the last one didn't. The error is:-

```
ValueError: shapes (2,) and (3,) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 3 (dim 0)
```

In my opinion,
in case 1, x = (1 row and 2 col)
in case 2, x = (2 row and 1 col)
in case 3, x should be (2 row and 1 col) but it didn't worked

Please let me know why this happened.

Comment: The numbers denotes the **value** of the array not the shape.

Comment: It's neither. It's a one dimensional array, has shape (2,).

Comment: What was the exact array contents you were expecting as a result of `np.dot(x,o)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [272]: x = np.array([1,2])
     ...: y = np.array([[1,3,5], [2,4,6]])
     ...: z = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
     ...: o = np.array([1,2,3])
     ...: 
In [273]: x.shape
Out[273]: (2,)              # 1 element tuple
In [274]: y.shape
Out[274]: (2, 3)            # 2 element tuple
In [275]: z.shape
Out[275]: (3, 2)
In [276]: o.shape
Out[276]: (3,)
```

The row/columns interpretation of dimensions fits the 2 arrays like `y` and `z`.  It's a poor fit with `x` and `o`.

We can make a 2d array from `x`, with one explicit row, 2 columns:

```
In [277]: x[None,:].shape
Out[277]: (1, 2)
```

But for many purposes the (2,) shape works just as well as the (1,2).

`np.dot` has well documented rules about how it handles 1d arrays.

The basic rule is the the sum-of-products is performed on the last dim of A, and 2nd to the last of B, with allowance for 1d.

```
x, y   (2,) with (2,3) => (3,)  (the 2's pair)
z, x   (3,2) with (2,) => (3,)  (the 2's pair)
x, o  (2,) with (3,)  no match!
```

A (n,2) will dot with (2,3) to produce a (n,3) result.  Likewise a (3,2) with (2,n) produces a (3,n).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "golden" rule while learning `numpy`: *When applying shape-compatibility rules, never think in terms of rows and columns.*

Having said that, here are the shape-compatibility rules for [`np.dot(a,b)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) (reproduced [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) as a **numbered** bullets)

> 1. If both a and b are 1-D arrays, it is inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation).
> 2. If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using matmul or a @ b is preferred.
> 3. If either a or b is 0-D (scalar), it is equivalent to multiply and using numpy.multiply(a, b) or a * b is preferred.
> 4. If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over the last axis of a and b.
> 5. If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b

(Notice that none of the rules are expressed in terms of *rows* and *columns*. They are expressed only in terms of the *dimensions* of the arrays `a` and `b`)

In our case:

`x` is a 1-D array (or "vector") with `2` elements.

`y` is a 2-D array with shape `(2,3)`.

`z` is a 2-D array with shape `(3,2)`.

`o` is a 1-D array (or "vector") with `3` elements.

For `np.dot(x,y)`, rule(5) applies.

For `np.dot(z,x)`, rule(4) applies.

For `np.dot(x,o)`, rule(1) is attempted, and fails, because you can't do an inner product of a vector of `2` elements, with another vector of `3` elements. (Both vectors need to have the same number of elements)

Comment: I totally understand. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your issue is here, when you have (X,) X implies number of elements and (X,Y) is x rows and Y cols

```
x.shape -> (2,) 2 elements
o.shape -> (3,) 3 elements
y.shape -> (2, 3) 2 rows 3 cols
z.shape -> (3, 2) 3 rows 2 cols
```

So
`np.dot(x,o)` will give you an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in dot
ValueError: shapes (2,) and (3,) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 3 (dim 0)
```

Comment: No, (3,) is 3 elements.  (1,3) is a 2d row/columns shape.

Comment: Yes I know I just wanted to use the `(r,c)` notation for the person to understand

Comment: @Kenan -- Any mention of rows and columns is ill-advised in the context of 1-dimensional arrays, and is the source of misunderstandings in learning numpy. Rows and columns should be mentioned strictly in the context of 2-dimensional arrays. So, I would rather say `x` does not have 1 row and 2 columns. It is just a 1-dimensional array, that's all.

Comment: Updated to help stop the spread of misunderstanding